# ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll referring to the previous file name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm finalizing this macro, so I changed my file name from "Tool_**test**.xlsm" to "Tool_**Final**.xlsm."

Then I noticed something weird happening. Every module that has this code:

```
Thisworkbook.RefreshAll
```

opens a dialogue box "Sorry, we couldn't find '...*filepath*...\Tool_**test**.xlsm.' Which is the old file path/name.

one of the modules is the following at its entirety:

```
Sub Clear_All()

If MsgBox("Erase all the data imported?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Sheets("Doc. Currency").Range("C135:N200").ClearContents
Sheets("Auto19").Range("A3:H531").ClearContents
Sheets("F08").Range("A2:E201").ClearContents

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Nothing more. Why does it keep refer to the old file?
"Thisworkbook." works fine everywhere, including in this module when I tested it. It seems "refreshall" is what's causing the problem, but I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Is that marco assigned to a button on  a sheet?

Comment: Does the old connection to Tool_test.xlsm still exist in your list of connections (Data menu>>Connections>>Connections)? If so, delete it.

Comment: @Gserg yes, the macro is assigned to a button on a sheet.

Comment: @MBB70 There was nothing in Data > connections. But thinking of your comment, I started checking every connectivity of all the objects within the workbook and figured out the issue! Thank you! (sorry my rep is too low to upvote comments!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

The issue was not the code.

The issue was that the pivot tables maintained its old reference even when the name of the file was changed. Solution was to select pivot > analyze > change data source >  re-assign the range.

If you plan to change the name of the file often, I guess it's better to make a macro to reproduce the pivot table or to update the range reference manually.

Please consider this issue resolved! And thank you for the comments!

Comment: Mark your answer as the answer and give yourself some points...I think that's how it works anyway :).